# Проблема подключения к postgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

Нужно подключится к БД potgeSQL и результаты вывести в JSON формате. Делаю так:

```
<?php

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');


$success = 'true';

$message = "Загруженные данные";



$connectString = 'host=localhost dbname=stocks_db user=postgres password=95161617';

$link = pg_connect($connectString);

if (!$link) {

    $success = 'false';

    $message = "Ошибка соединения";

} else {
    $sql = "select *, open - last as change from stocks";

    if( !$result = pg_query($link, $sql) ) {

        $success = 'false';

        $message = "Ошибка выполнения запроса";

    };

    $rows = array();

    while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {


        switch ($r['split']) {
            case 't': $r['split']=true;
                break;
            case 'f': $r['split']=false;
                break;
        }
        $rows[] = $r;


    }

}

print "{\"success\":$success,\"message\":\"$message\",\"data\":";

print json_encode($rows);

print "}";
?>
```

Но в результате - пустая вкладка в браузере!!

**Какая в меня ошибка ? Как ее исправить  ???**

Comment: У вас есть две функции http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pg-last-error.php  и еще  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pg-result-error.php а вы нас спрашиваете какая у вас ошибка? ..........в какой IDE вы разрабатываете? В блокноте? Ведь даже редактор stackoverflow вам показывает что нет кавычки после `Ошибка выполнения запроса` а уж любой приличный редактор тем более показывает

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, извиняюсь..В phpStorm у меня стоят кавычки все, видимо при копировании так получилось!

Comment: Ок. тем не менее я вам показал как минимум две функции с помощью которых вы можете узнать какие у вас ошибки.... более того вы можете включить отображение ошибок в `php` чтоб тот тоже мог показать ваши ошибки..`ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`

Comment: Такой запрос `select *, open - last as change from stocks` так и задумано? пробелы в `open - last ` ... и есть ли такая колонка?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, бросает такую ошибку Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_connect() in /var/www/mysite/lab2/stocks.php on line 17

Comment: в `ini` файле закоменчена строка значит `extension=php_pgsql.dll` а также в папке `php/ext` возможно нет самой `dll`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в ini вообще нет такой строки

Comment: Тем более, как вы собрались использовать постгресс, раз в пхп у вас не установлено ничего? Не удивительно... установите и пользуйтесь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, устанавливал модуль sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо....я разобрался! )